# Get specific PHP array element

Tags: php, arrays, element

How would I call in php to get just the Pharmacy StoreName for this array?  I don't want to have to loop through each key and assign variables, just go to a specific one if possible?

Thanks for your help!

```
Array
(
    [@attributes] => Array
    (
       [version] => 010
       [release] => 006
    )
    [Header] => Array
    (
       [To] => 6891118750001
       [From] => 9911557
       [MessageID] => c47930abcf1540798f95e8fa1eac591f
       [RelatesToMessageID] => 4c8be0841c9b4ed0e53148db790bcd5a
       [SentTime] => 2014-10-06T15:25:02.2Z
       [Security] => Array
       (
          [Sender] => Array
          (
              [TertiaryIdentification] => 165
          )
         [Receiver] => Array
         (
            [TertiaryIdentification] => 2341
         )
      )
      [RxReferenceNumber] => RxRef# REFREQ 2.1
      [PrescriberOrderNumber] => 87
   )
   [Body] => Array
   (
      [RefillRequest] => Array
      ( 
         [Pharmacy] => Array
         (
            [Identification] => Array
            (
               [NCPDPID] => 9911557
               [NPI] => 1801849179
            )
            [StoreName] => CA Pharmacy 10.6MU
            [Address] => Array
            (
               [AddressLine1] => 65432 Cabernet Turn
               [City] => Sonoma
               [State] => CA
               [ZipCode] => 95476
            )
...blah blah
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work

Comment: Without proper indentation it's eye-bleedingly difficult to see where exactly that key is nested in. But you'll simply have to use the right nested key, something along the lines of `$array['Body']['Pharmacy']['StoreName']`.

Comment: Indent your data structure and its **PAINFULLY OBVIOUS**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply with:

```
$your_array['Body']['RefillRequest']['Pharmacy']['StoreName'];
```